# Using/Substituting a Coin Cell Battery

Tags: bluetooth, batteries

I wish to run an MCU (for bluetooth to be specific) which commonly runs on a coin cell battery. I was wondering if it was possible to replace the regular CR2032 battery with the smaller and cheaper hearing aid batteries ([e.g.](http://www.microbattery.com/tech-energizer-hearing-aid-battery)). The CR2032 has a typical capacity of about 240mAh, and I can see the orange "13" (PR48) battery in the link has a capacity of about 280mAh. Given that the voltage is almost half that of the CR2032, would I be able to replace the CR2032 for 2 of the smaller PR48 batteries in series to get the same result in operation?

I don't know a lot about electronics so please explain why or why not...

Comment: check esr and your current needs

Answer (score 2):

The PR48 may be rated for 1.4 volts "nominal", but if you inspect the data sheet closely, the actual voltage is closer to 1.15v to 1.2v. Not sure if your bluetooth could run with 1.2 + 1.2 = 2.4 volts.   Doesn't look too good as far as voltage is concerned.  The CR2032 does show about 3 volts under load.

I was surprised at the ampacity of the zinc air (even though I use them and wear a hearing aid, I had never looked up the ampacity of zinc air.

EDIT :  Added link to CR2032 : http://na.industrial.panasonic.com/sites/default/pidsa/files/crseries_datasheets_merged.pdf